# No module named 'PIL' after pip installing it

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Pillow in my python(tkinter) project. I used `pip install Pillow` to install the package.

When I type `from PIL import ImageTk, Image` and try to run my code I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL`. I tried several things like updating pip, uninstalling Pillow and reinstalling it again, using different commands to install it etc.

I don't know what to do now since I never had this problem before. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Try using `python -m pip install pillow` to ensure you are using same Python environment.  Replace `python` by `python3` if necessary.

Comment: for what it is worth, your syntax is fine (I copy/pasted yours).  I was able to `pip install Pillow` and then make a fake little program and import OK.  Are other modules importing OK?

Comment: Where should I use this `python -m pip install pillow`? Because if I use it in my project folder I get the `Requirement already satisfied` message.

Comment: Then try `python -m PIL` and it should show some information on the module.

Comment: @acw1668 it shows this: https://pastebin.com/Pe0bTzgB
It seems like it should work right?

Comment: If you get that information, it should work.

Comment: @acw1668 that is what I got but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you run your script using a console? Or you use some IDE? If using IDE, make sure the Python used is the same as the one used for the above testing.

Comment: @PiiMY: Did you try using `python3 -m pip install pillow`, as acw1668 suggested? If that didn't work, did you try `pip3 install pillow`? Oftentimes using `python -m pip install` installs in Python 2, not in Python 3.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Under Windows, both Python 2 and 3 are using `python.exe`.

Comment: @acw1668:Did the OP say that they are using Windows? And aside from the fact that both Python 2 and 3 _are_ using the same `.exe` file, they are still different interpreters. Does Windows automatically install modules in both Python 2 and Python 3, regardless of whether you run `python -m pip install` or `python3 -m pip install`?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin From the information in the pastebin link by OP, OP is using Windows.  Since both Python 2 and 3 in Windows use same `python.exe`, the one found in `PATH` environment variable will be used.  Or you can use full path to the `python.exe`.  Normally I would create batch file `python3.bat` for Python 3 and `python2.bat` for Python 2.

Comment: @acw1668 Doesn't the `PATH` environment variable point to a separate interpreter anyway? In which case, the OP can still use the `python3` command? I'm not sure I'm quite clear on this. Are you saying that the `python3` command can't be used on Windows without using `.bat` files? Won't running `python3` run whatever Python 3 interpreter the `PATH` variable points to?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I used all the commands you gave me but still the same error. I used it with "Pillow" and "pillow" just in case it's capital sensitive. And yes I'm using windows :)

Comment: @PiiMY Okay, thanks for letting me know :-)! I don't use or know Windows, so I'm afraid that I won't be of much help here. Please consider answering acw1668's [comment;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661846/no-module-named-pil-after-pip-installing-it?noredirect=1#comment123137287_69661846) maybe the solution lies there...

Comment: @acw1668 I  did the pip install commands in my CMD and in the terminal in my VSC. (in the project folder)

Comment: Try using `python -m pip install pillow` in the *terminal of VSC*.  There are similar questions on VSC have been asked in StackOverflow, so try searching about the issue in SO.

Comment: Or using the python plugin of VSC to install pillow.